# Python iteration to generate new empty variables

Tags: python, loops

Assuming df1 to df10 are new variables and not assigned with any values. Any possibility to write a For loop to generate all of them with empty values? (I can generate strings but not new variables)

list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10]

Comment: use a dictionary

Comment: use a dict or a list